# TensorFlow failed to connect to TensorFlow master. TPU may not be ready

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am following the BERT TPU tutorial for GCP. https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert

However, at the training step, I encounter the following error and could proceed to the training:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Failed to connect to the Tensorflow master. The TPU worker may not be ready (still scheduling) or the Tensorflow master address is incorrect: got (grpc://10.240.1.2:8470).
W0404 03:06:16.688671 139878329321216 tpu_system_metadata.py:97] Failed to connect to the Tensorflow master. The TPU worker may not be ready (still scheduling) or the Tensorflow master address is incorrect: got (grpc://10.240.1.2:8470).
WARNING:tensorflow:Retrying (2/288).
W0404 03:06:16.688920 139878329321216 tpu_system_metadata.py:98] Retrying (2/288).
INFO:tensorflow:Querying Tensorflow master (grpc://10.240.1.2:8470) for TPU system metadata.
I0404 03:06:16.689001 139878329321216 tpu_system_metadata.py:78] Querying Tensorflow master (grpc://10.240.1.2:8470) for TPU system metadata.
2020-04-04 03:06:16.690159: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_session.cc:370] GrpcSession::ListDevices will initialize the session with an empty graph and other defaults because the session has not yet been created.
```

Does anybody have an idea what could cause that problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: First confirm no other session using TPU  in google colab ?

Comment: This issue is usually related to networking issues between your project and TPU's internal project. It is sometimes resolved by deactivating and reactivating AI Platform Training & Prediction API. It will always be resolved by the training in a new project.

Comment: I solved it by pausing the VM (`ctpu pause`) and then lifting it up again (`ctpu up`)